# Screen loads from middle in Android

Tags: android

I am creating an app similar to flipkart. I have viewpager with images and I have horizontal scroll gridview to load products like new products, favourite products, best products so on.

Everything is loading fine accept that strange issue when I open the app the app automatically shows from the middle.

How do I force it to show the screen from top rather than middle.

For Slideshow I am using viewpager and for horizontal scrollview I am using TwoWayGridView API.

Has anybody come across this issue? How do I force the app to run from the top?

Please check the screenshot below:

[image]

The above screen shows the screen loads in the middle and not from top.

PS: This is from flipkart app. Showing how it would show on my app? Sorry not allowed to share the app's design part.

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked" })
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        if (rootView != null) 
        {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) rootView.getParent();

            if (parent != null)
                parent.removeView(rootView);
        }
        try 
        {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
        } 
        catch (InflateException e) 
        {

        }

        TextView[] bestproduct = new TextView[] 
                { 
                (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bestproduct1),
                (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bestproduct2),
                };


        RelativeLayout [] relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout[] 
                { 
                (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1),
                (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout2),
  };

        bannerItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        newproductList = new ArrayList<ProductFrontScreenDetails>();

        dbmaster = new dbMaster(getActivity());
        customerID = dbmaster.getCustID();

        final ScrollView main = (ScrollView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
        main.scrollTo(0,0);

        progressContainer = rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressContainer);
        progressContainer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        viewPager = (ViewPager)rootView.findViewById(R.id.myviewpager);
        myPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(myPagerAdapter);

        mIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator)rootView.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        mIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);

        TAG_SUCCESS = getResources().getString(R.string.tagsuccess);
        TAG_DETAIL = getResources().getString(R.string.tagdetails);
        TAG_IMAGE = getResources().getString(R.string.productimage);
        TAG_NAME = getResources().getString(R.string.productname);
        TAG_BANNER_IMAGE = getResources().getString(R.string.bannerimage);
        TAG_PRICE = getResources().getString(R.string.productprice);
        TAG_DISCOUNT = getResources().getString(R.string.productdiscount);

        FetchBannerImagesData();

        gridViewnew = (TwoWayGridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.newproductgridview);
        gridViewnew.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(TwoWayAdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
            {
                                }

        });

        gridView1 = (TwoWayGridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        gridView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(TwoWayAdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
            {

            }

        });

        gridView2 = (TwoWayGridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView2);
        gridView2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(TwoWayAdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
            {

        }

        });
     return rootView;
}
```

Comment: so basically scroll to the top on loading?

Comment: Yep. I tried this  main.scrollTo(0,0); but didn't work

Comment: can you post any code?

Comment: Sure. what do you want?

Comment: @JABFreeware : Can you help with this?